# how to build Dropdownmenu using flutter FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

hi i want to build dropdown menu using FutureBuilder in Flutter because i'm fetching json from API, I'm new in flutter so i tried and i could not do it
here is my code

```
   Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getmodelsformake/honda?format=json');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  int count;
  String message;
  String searchCriteria;
  List<Results> results;

  Album({this.count, this.message, this.searchCriteria, this.results});

  Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    count = json['Count'];
    message = json['Message'];
    searchCriteria = json['SearchCriteria'];
    if (json['Results'] != null) {
      results = new List<Results>();
      json['Results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Results {
  int makeID;
  String makeName;
  int modelID;
  String modelName;

  Results({this.makeID, this.makeName, this.modelID, this.modelName});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    makeID = json['Make_ID'];
    makeName = json['Make_Name'];
    modelID = json['Model_ID'];
    modelName = json['Model_Name'];
  }
}
```

i want to build a DropDownMenuList for all modelID

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
code snippet

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Album> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('none');
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Text('');
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(
                '${snapshot.error}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              );
            } else {
              return DropdownButton<Results>(
                isExpanded: true,
                items:
                    snapshot.data.results.map((Results dropDownStringItem) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Results>(
                    value: dropDownStringItem,
                    child: Text(dropDownStringItem.modelID.toString()),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selected = value;
                  });
                },
                value: _selected,
              );
            }
        }
      })
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Album {
  int count;
  String message;
  String searchCriteria;
  List<Results> results;

  Album({this.count, this.message, this.searchCriteria, this.results});

  Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    count = json['Count'];
    message = json['Message'];
    searchCriteria = json['SearchCriteria'];
    if (json['Results'] != null) {
      results = [];
      json['Results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Results {
  int makeID;
  String makeName;
  int modelID;
  String modelName;

  Results({this.makeID, this.makeName, this.modelID, this.modelName});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    makeID = json['Make_ID'];
    makeName = json['Make_Name'];
    modelID = json['Model_ID'];
    modelName = json['Model_Name'];
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<Album> _future;
  Results _selected;

  Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getmodelsformake/honda?format=json');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = fetchAlbum();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Album> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('none');
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              case ConnectionState.active:
                return Text('');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(
                    '${snapshot.error}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  );
                } else {
                  return DropdownButton<Results>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    items:
                        snapshot.data.results.map((Results dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<Results>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(dropDownStringItem.modelID.toString()),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selected = value;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _selected,
                  );
                }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work.

```
FutureBuilder<Album>(
      future: fetchAlbum(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final album = snapshot.data;
          final results = album.results;
          return DropdownButton<Results>(
              items: results.map((result) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<Results>(
                  value: result,
                  child: Text('${result.modelID}'),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (album) {
                // selected album
              });
        } else
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
      });
```