# flutter application that populates a dropdown menu from json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I am a newbie in flutter and I'm trying to create 3 dropdown menus from a json file hosted online. Here is a sample of the json file. This is the link to the [json file](https://jsonkeeper.com/b/6FNV) and this is the model class:

```dart
class DropdownModel {
    DropdownModel({
        this.sports,
        this.movies,
        this.tv,
    });

    List<Movie> sports;
    List<Movie> movies;
    List<Movie> tv;

    factory DropdownModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DropdownModel(
        sports: List<Movie>.from(json["sports"].map((x) => Movie.fromJson(x))),
        movies: List<Movie>.from(json["movies"].map((x) => Movie.fromJson(x))),
        tv: List<Movie>.from(json["tv"].map((x) => Movie.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "sports": List<dynamic>.from(sports.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "movies": List<dynamic>.from(movies.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "tv": List<dynamic>.from(tv.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Movie {
    Movie({
        this.id,
        this.name,
    });

    int id;
    String name;

    factory Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Movie(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

How do I go about it?

**EDIT**

After searching around got a solution I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547648/how-to-build-dropdownmenu-using-flutter-futurebuilder)  which answers my question

Answer (score 0):

An example would be:

```dart
// Let's supose you have a variable of the DropdownModel
DropwdownModel model = DropdownModel(...);

// We store the current dropdown value
// Here you can put the default option
// Since you have Movies with id, I would recommend saving
// the movie value as the dropdownValue
String dropdownValue = '';

// For example, let's use the music
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // We define the dropdown button
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    // The value is the selected value, you should control the state
    value: model.fromNameFromId(dropdownValue),
    // The icon to open the dropdown
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
    iconSize: 24,
    elevation: 16,
    // On changed is the method that it is called when a dropdown option
    // is selected
    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
      // Here we change the state, as I noted before
      // The newValue will be a movie id
      setState(() {
        dropdownValue = newValue!;
      });
    },
    items: model.movies.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
      // We have to iterate through all the movies and return 
      // a list of DropdownMenuItems
      (Movie m) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: m.id,
          // We display the movie name instead of the id
          child: Text(m.name),
        );
      })
      .toList(),
  );
}
```

If you want three dropdowns, you would have to create three DropdownButton! You can find more information in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)!